# json parsed listview with different type of item

Tags: android, json, listview, custom-adapter

[image]I parsed a `JSON` api and put it in `ListView`. I have different type item, like Video, Audio, Image, and text.
Means in one row, may I have sound with play button and other options.
I know that should I use of `GetViewTypeCount()` and getViewItemType().

JSON is like this

```
{
category: {
id: 2,
image: "/ringtone/media/cats/music.png",
title: "VARIOUS"
},
create_time: "2014-01-05T23:21:10",
file_url: "/media/sound/verysadrin_OnlRtRGn.mp3",
id: 28,
title: "Sad",
user: {
avatar: "/media/daddy_avatar/100/346186098ce0fc27be1ddbd95dcac2cf_100.jpg",
id: 12,
name: "MAY3AM"
}
},
{
category: {
id: 22,
image: "/ringtone/media/cats/video.png",
title: "VARIOUS_VIDEO"
},
create_time: "2014-02-05T23:21:10",
file_url: "/media/video/verysadrin_OnlR105n.mp4",
id: 28,
title: "Sad",
user: {
avatar: "/media/daddy_avatar/100/346186098ce0fc27be1ddbd95dcac2cf_100.jpg",
id: 12,
name: "MAY3AM"
}
},
{
category: {
id: 22,
image: "/ringtone/media/cats/video.png",
title: "NATURE"
},
create_time: "2014-03-05T23:21:10",
file_url: "/media/video/landscape.jpg",
id: 28,
title: "Landscape",
user: {
avatar: "/media/daddy_avatar/100/346186098ce0fc27be1ddbd95dcac2cf_100.jpg",
id: 12,
name: "MAY3AM"
}
},
```

As you can see I have more then one type ( sound, video and image and text). I want to parse them in a listview by a CustomAdapter! I want to inflate each row to proper xml file based on json object type. means if my json object was sound inflat it to `R.layout.sound.xml`, if was video inflate to `R.layout.Video.xml` and....

But I can't figure out this part, how can say to my CustomAdapte to determine when show particular view?!
You know what, I searched in Stack, some answers say something like `contact list` that you want to show in odd and even row, or like list view with `separator` that put separator for each 4 or 5 row...

But I don't want something like that, Because I parsed a json and base on that data should show the proper row type.

how I must tell to custom adapter that this row must inflate to sound xml file or Video xml file or other types?!

Can someone explain it for some code for me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a **custom adapter** for your listview, where you can inflate different views inside `getView()` method.

**Pseudo code can be:**

```
getView() {
  if(video item) 
    inflate video item row xml layout
  else if(image item)
    inflate image item row xml layout
  else if(audio item)
    inflate audio item row xml layout
  else if(text item)
    inflate text item row xml layout
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i know that, but how determine video, image and so... in this?!

Comment: How should i defined video, image, audio, text in if statement?